# Vaadin + Springboot on AWS Lambda generates NPE

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-security, vaadin-flow

I have a Vaadinflow + Springboot application. I want to deploy this to AWS lambda I have the necessary dependencies in place. However on deploying to aws lambda and invoking the endpoint I get Gateway timeout. In the cloudwatch logs I see this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.getContext()" because "service" is null.
```

Complete stack trace

```
2024-01-30T11:34:24.443Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.a.s.l.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda     : Starting AWSLambda v2.4.1 using Java 21.0.1 with PID 8 (/var/runtime/lib/aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client-2.4.1-linux-x86_64.jar started by sbx_user1051 in /var/task)
2024-01-30T11:34:24.445Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.a.s.l.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-30T11:34:25.654Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.servlet.AwsServletContext      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-01-30T11:34:25.656Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1109 ms
2024-01-30T11:34:26.178Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@76e90da5, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4e3e11b9, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@1d0cac30, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@f0a66bd, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@67cffead, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@2bbb44da, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@50b0afd7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@4207852d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5dfe23e8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@583fb274, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@214beff9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6707a4bf, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@9dada78]
2024-01-30T11:34:26.471Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.a.s.l.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda     : Started AWSLambda in 2.507 seconds (process running for 4.001)
2024-01-30T11:34:26.475Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.servlet.AwsServletContext      : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-01-30T11:34:26.476Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-01-30T11:34:26.476Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
START RequestId: 82d4cb29-d5f7-4422-beee-290eb18216fc Version: $LATEST
2024-01-30T11:34:26.676Z ERROR 8 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.internal.LambdaContainerHandler  : Error while handling request
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.getContext()" because "service" is null
at com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.WebIconsRequestMatcher.initMatchers(WebIconsRequestMatcher.java:78) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.3.jar:na]
at com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.WebIconsRequestMatcher.<init>(WebIconsRequestMatcher.java:66) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.3.jar:na]
at com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.RequestUtil.isCustomWebIcon(RequestUtil.java:143) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.3.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher.matcher(RequestMatcher.java:48) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.check(RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.java:79) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.check(RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.java:48) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:95) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:225) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.FilterChainHolder.doFilter(FilterChainHolder.java:90) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.FilterChainHolder.doFilter(FilterChainHolder.java:90) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.FilterChainHolder.doFilter(FilterChainHolder.java:90) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.FilterChainHolder.doFilter(FilterChainHolder.java:90) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M2.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsLambdaServletContainerHandler.doFilter(AwsLambdaServletContainerHandler.java:154) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M2.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:174) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-springboot3-2.0.0-M2.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:47) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-springboot3-2.0.0-M2.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:214) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M2.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxyStream(LambdaContainerHandler.java:257) ~[aws-serverless-java-container-core-2.0.0-M2.jar:na]
at de.phani.StreamLambdaHandler.handleRequest(StreamLambdaHandler.java:37) ~[task/:na]
```

Has anyone come across this error? Any references on how to solve?

This is my pom

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-springboot3</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M2</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <version>24.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <version>24.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Locally everything is working properly The only change I do when running locally is that I do not exclude spring-boot-starter-tomcat as I am doing now.

FYI : I started out with aws-serverless-springboot3-archetype maven archetype and deployed onto lambda and checked if everything is working.
Then I added vaadin and spring security dependencies and deployed onto lambda, this is when I have the issue.

I also tried removing spring security related code. Then I get this error

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.server.StaticFileHandler.serveStaticResource(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)" because "this.staticFileHandler" is null
```

**UPDATE**:

I added the production profile into my pom as mentioned https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/production-build#enabling-production-builds
I packaged the jar using command

```
mvn clean package -Pproduction
```

With this, I get the following error on AWS lambda.

```
Error loading class de.phani.handler.StreamLambdaHandler: com/amazonaws/serverless/exceptions/ContainerInitializationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/serverless/exceptions/ContainerInitializationException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is there a full stack trace? That could help. Are you making a production build of the application?

Comment: I have updated the complete stack trace. No I am not running in production build. I started of with aws-serverless-springboot3-archetype and added vaadin dependencies. Am I missing something here

Comment: Yes, you need to make a production build if you are not running in development mode locally. The AWS deployment documentation might help: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/cloud-providers/aws. If you want to read more about production builds: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/production-build

Comment: @ollitietavainen I made the production build, still i have issues. please check my edit. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The second error doesn't seem to have anything to do with Vaadin, so it would make sense to separate that into a different question

Comment: okay what about this error because "this.staticFileHandler" is null. do u have an example of running vaadin application on aws lambda?

Comment: Ah, problem is probably that you need sessions to run a Vaadin app, which isn't going to work in serverless Lambda. You need to use a different type of cloud service, such as AWS Elastic Beanstalk.